# Like Button React Native - Firebase

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement the like button in my app.

I can add and remove the like without problems, but when I restart the app, the Like is removed from the database.

And I'm not able to do the counter either ...

```js
    //func likeImage...
    likeImage = (postid) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            let liked = Object.assign({}, prevState.liked);
            liked[postid] = !liked[postid];
            return { liked };
        });
    }

    //add value on firebase
    setLike(postid) {
        const { liked } = this.state
        const imageValue = liked[postid]
            ? database.ref('Likes').child(postid).child(auth.currentUser.uid).set(true) && require("../assets/heart.png")
            : database.ref('Likes').child(postid).child(auth.currentUser.uid).remove() && require("../assets/heart-outline.png")

        //Only image...
        //? require("../assets/heart.png")
        //: require("../assets/heart-outline.png")

        return imageValue
    }


     //button like
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.likeImage(post.postid)}>
         <Image source={this.setLike(post.postid)}
            style={{ width: 24, height: 24, marginEnd: 10 }}
            resizeMode="cover"
         />
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: If the node gets deleted it seems that `liked[postid]` is false, empty, or non-existent. From the code you shared it's hard to say why that is.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying! When started it is empty.

```constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            liked: {},
        }
```

Comment: So that explains why the database contents get deleted then. You'll want your code to make the distinction between "not loaded yet" and "loaded, but false".